# Multi website and multi store view with custom base url in magento 2

Tags: php, magento, nginx, magento2

I have a magento 2 installed and configured the following:

1. base website with 1 store view called us_en
2. eu website with 1 store view called eu_en

I have added nginx configurations to pass MAGE_RUN_TYPE and MAGE_RUN_CODE

For assigning mage_code based on request uri,

```
map $request_uri $mage_code {
        ~^/us/ us_en;
        ~^/eu/ eu_en;
}
```

And passing the $mage_code as fastcgi param to magento

```
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $mage_code;
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
```

When I change base url to store view as domain_name/us/en or domain_name/eu/en that store view fails to load, even the cms pages located in domain_name/about_us not loading.

I suspect I am missing a step with respect to magento router.

Any pointers?